# SQL: Counting the number of rows whose sum reaches a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having

I have a data that looks like more or less like this table. Let's call this "*expenses*" table.

| date | transportation | fruits | vegetables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-25 | 10 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-05-26 | 10 | 0 | 40 |
| 2022-05-27 | 10 | 20 | 40 |
| 2022-05-28 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2022-05-29 | 10 | 0 | 60 |
| 2022-05-30 | 10 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-05-31 | 10 | 10 | 40 |
| 2022-06-01 | 10 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-06-02 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2022-06-03 | 10 | 30 | 40 |
| 2022-06-04 | 10 | 0 | 20 |
| 2022-06-05 | 10 | 30 | 30 |
| 2022-06-06 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2022-06-07 | 10 | 0 | 30 |
| 2022-06-08 | 10 | 0 | 30 |
| 2022-06-09 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| 2022-06-10 | 10 | 30 | 30 |

I want to know how many days, for the months of May and June, the sum of *fruits* and *vegetables* was equal to or greater than 50.

The answer that I'm expecting to get is **4 days for May** (05-27,05-28, 05-29, 05-31) and **5 days for June** (06-02, 06-03, 06-05, 06-06, 06-10)

I tried to use this script, however...

**SELECT** date_format(date, '%M' '%Y'), **COUNT**(date)
**FROM** expenses
**GROUP BY** date_format(date, '%M' '%Y')
**HAVING** SUM(fruits + vegetables)>=50

...instead of counting only the number days per month whose sum of *fruits* and *vegetables* was equal to or greater than 50, it counts all days in the table for the two months, that is to say, it yields an answer of 7 days for May and 10 days for June.

I am using the latest version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `having` clause, filter the rows with `Where`.

**Query**

```
select date_format(date, '%M' '%Y') as month, count(*) as no_of_days
from expenses
where fruits + vegetables >= 50
group by date_format(date, '%M' '%Y');
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e38bba/14)**